# Python how to start at index 1? function to find the month

Tags: python, python-3.x

I am trying to create a function that will give me all the error messages below, is there a way I can start the index to start from 1?

```
def getMonth(month):
    try:
        list_of_month_index0 = ['Jan', 'Feb','March','April','May','June','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
        return list_of_month_index0[month]
    except IndexError:
            return 'ERROR: out of range!'
    except :
            return 'ERROR: invalid number!'

getMonth('a') # 'ERROR: invalid number!'
getMonth(13) # ERROR: out of range!
getMonth(1) # Jan
getMonth(0) # ERROR: out of range!
```

Comment: Just write `list_of_month_index0[month + 1]`?

Comment: Hi Lev, That give me February for the month of 1

Comment: Ok, simply check index in if statement and then return `list_of_month_index0[month - 1]`.

Answer (score 2):

You're out by 1, right? So change the index by 1:

```
def getMonth(month):
    try:
        list_of_month_index0 = ['Jan', 'Feb','March','April','May','June','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
        if month < 1 or month > len(list_of_month_index0):
            return 'ERROR: out of range!'
        return list_of_month_index0[month - 1]
    except:
        return 'ERROR: invalid number!'
```

Comment: Hi Alex, That gives me "Dec" when I call getMonth(0). It needs to be 'ERROR: out of range!'

Comment: Ah, but that's a different question. The catch-all `except` at the end could theoretically occur for more than just invalid numbers.

Comment: Sorry, Taylor, just had a look at it..it working perfectly :)\

Answer (score 2):

The standard library already includes month names, collected in lists of thirteen elements, with the empty string as the initial element, in the [calendar](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/calendar.html#module-calendar) module.

> [calendar.month_abbr](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_abbr)
>
> An array that represents the abbreviated months of the year in the current locale. This follows normal convention of January being month
>   number 1, so it has a length of 13 and month_abbr[0] is the empty
>   string.

([calendar.month_name](https://docs.python.org/3.7/library/calendar.html#calendar.month_name) contains the unabbreviated names).

You could use this array in your function like this, if you don't mind mixing some boolean logic with your try/except structure.

```
>>> def get_month(month):
...     OUT_OF_RANGE = 'ERROR: out of range!'
...     try:
...         m = calendar.month_abbr[month]
...     except IndexError:
...         return OUT_OF_RANGE
...     except TypeError:    
...     # if _month_ isn't an integer you'll get a TypeError.
...         return 'ERROR: invalid number!'
...     # If the input is zero, m is the empty string, which evaluates to
...     # False in a boolean context, so the error message is returned.
...     return m or OUT_OF_RANGE  
... 
>>> get_month('a')
'ERROR: invalid number!'
>>> get_month('13')
'ERROR: invalid number!'
>>> get_month(1)
'Jan'
>>> get_month(0)
'ERROR: out of range!'
```

Answer (score 0):

```
def getMonth(month):
    try:
        list_of_month= ['Jan', 'Feb','March','April','May','June','July','Aug','Sep','Oct','Nov','Dec']
        if month<1 or month>12:
            raise IndexError('ERROR: out of range!')
        else:
            return list_of_month[month - 1]
    except IndexError as x:
        return '{0}'.format(x)
    except:
        return 'ERROR: invalid number!'
```